# Will Physics become Math?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, mathematics

There are conflicting theories in Physics. For example, GR is only good in astronomical scale but not in quantum scale, and vice versa.  Unlike in Mathematics where formulas are universal, a theory or equation in Physics is good only up to a point when it has to give way to another theory/law of Physics.

I have heard people say that some fields, like Chemistry, are now "developed" -- meaning you don't expect a new discovery that will turn upside down its very fundamentals. But in Physics, the Galilean concepts were fine tuned by Newtonian theories, then revised by Einstein's relativity which were then challenged by quantum theories.

Can we expect that Physics, evolving as it is now, will someday be fully "developed"?  Or will it be forever be evolving and developing?

Comment: It is clearly an opinion-based question. Feynman believed that one day all physics problems would be resolved. I am less convinced about it, but it is clear that most "physicists" today are doing math and/or engineering rather than solving real scientific problem. There is a lot more place for discoveries in biology and other places... but they look so *unstructured* to physicist raised on already discovered nice and neat equations.

Comment: 1,000 years of scientific development maybe equivalent to 3-M years of Darwinian evolution, e.g, from Lucy (the first ape to walk bi-pedal) to Homo Sapien was 3.2-M yrs. 
It took roughly 1000-yr for human thought to evolve from conquering himself (beliefs, religion) to conquering his planet (technological stuffs borne from Earth resources). 
It may take another 1000-yr timeline for humans to conquer the solar system, (e.g, terraforming Mars/Venus, re-arranging planets the way we like).  
Then another thousand yrs to conquer the power of Milky Way (e.g, teleporting, intra-galactic travel).

Comment: I think you are confusing "physics" and "engineering". E.g., conquering solar system will not necessarily bring us new knowledge about the laws of physics.

Comment: By "conquering the solar system", I mean harnessing the power of the Sun (and resources of the earth) to do something we cannot do now, say re-arranging the planets like moving Earth past Mars or Jupiter.  This will certainly require humans to learn new knowledge and develop new "toys".